# login shell without password on nixos/nixops

Tags: nixos, nixops

## what i want

i'm using `nixops` to deploy to `VirtualBox` and `libvirtd` (KVM) and on both environments i would like it if the shell did not have a login with username/password bust instead would already provide a logged in shell.

- for libvirt we have: `virsh console myfancydeploymentname`
- for VirtualBox we have: the graphical interface or some `vboxmanage` command

## source

maybe it is just an extension here:

https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#logind

or

https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#tty

any pointer would be lovely!

Comment: `services.mingetty.autologinUser = "root";` is the solution. thought i tried this in the past already but this is just it!

Comment: If you found the solution, you can post it as an answer to this question and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

just set `services.mingetty.autologinUser = "root";` and there won't be any prompt.